# GCM message not delivered to device

Tags: cordova, google-cloud-messaging, ionic-framework, pushwoosh

My client side is ionic
I use Pushwoosh plugin for cordova
I get the registration id for the device

When I try to send push via php it returns success:

```
{"multicast_id":6883252716420444367,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1427630476543385%5628e13ff9fd7ecd"}]}
```

but the message isn't received on the device

When I use the Pushwoosh admin it works, and the device receives the push

I know that the php code is good, because it works for another app and the same device

That confuses me, because if there was a problem with the Android manifest, How come I'm able to send via the Pushwoosh admin?

Here is the manifest:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="com.ionicframework.afteru988615" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="CordovaApp" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.ionicframework.afteru988615.MESSAGE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.arellomobile.android.push.PushWebview" />
    <activity android:name="com.arellomobile.android.push.MessageActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.arellomobile.android.push.PushHandlerActivity" />
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" />
    <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.ionicframework.afteru988615" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="com.arellomobile.android.push.PushGCMIntentService" />
    <service android:name="com.arellomobile.android.push.GeoLocationService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.arellomobile.android.push.AlarmReceiver" />
</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<permission android:name="com.ionicframework.afteru988615.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.ionicframework.afteru988615.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" /></manifest>
```

Comment: I would suggest enabling debug mode in Pushwoosh control panel and to check push status.